# How to disable UglifyJsPlugin warnings if plugin is enabled?

Tags: webpack

When webpack is run with the `-p` option, it enables `--optimize-minimize` which is equivalent to `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin()` in thewebpack config.

This outputs a lot of warnings that are not very interesting. How can I disable these warnings?

I know that I can put `new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({ compress: { warnings: false }})` in `plugins` but this seems to enable the plugins for non-`-p` builds as well.